# how to pass dynamic value in @include as blade name in laravel5.4

Tags: laravel-5

This is my code in laravel blade

```
 @foreach($modules as $module)          // {{ mod.$module['module_name'] }} 
                                             giving me right value

 @section('content')
 @include("mod.$module['module_name']") // mod is my folder name and 
                                          $module['module_name'] value is 
                                          coming from database
 @endsection

@endforeach
```

{{ mod.$module['module_name'] }} is giving me correct value but when i pass it to @include it gives me error. Please help me !!!

Comment: What is the error?  In general here, the more details you give the better answers you get.  I don't remember the syntax for the include command but I know that what you have a syntax error if this were plain PHP.  Have you tried `@include("mod.{$module['module_name']}")`?

Comment: error => syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: yes i  tried @include("mod.{$module['module_name']}") but stiil get error

Comment: You should include relevant line from your compiled template.  Looking at that error, my suspicion is that laravel doesn't support doing that the way you are trying to do that... back in a few

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it has to do with the way the blade template translates the @include directive into compiled PHP.  Including the snippet from the compiled PHP file would help, but try this:

```
@include( 'mod.' . $module['module_name'] )
```

Looking at some of my past code, you can definitely use a variable in an include.  In my case I simply built the desired filename in the controller and passed it along to the view, so my include statement was simply:

```
@include( $filename )
```

Comment: Thanks bro , @include( 'mod.' . $module['module_name'] ) solution work like a charm. Thanks a lot

Comment: I appreciate your effots